# React - accessing object's child in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do a simple page where I list information from a data structure.

I try to access the object's children inside the Component `CountryInfo`.
I believe I'm using `data` wrong, in the way I'm trying to access the children. But I just can't figure out how.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import countries from 'world-countries'


const CountryInfo = data =>{
    return(
      <p>{data.name} {data.area} km<sup>2</sup></p>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <CountryInfo data={countries[0]}/>
      {console.log(countries[0].area)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I use `console.log(countries[0].area)` the output is correct (`180`).
The desired output is "Aruba 180km2".

This is what `countries` look like:

```
 Array (250 items)
0: Object
altSpellings: ["AW"]
area: 180
borders: []
capital: ["Oranjestad"]
cca2: "AW"
cca3: "ABW"
ccn3: "533"
cioc: "ARU"
currencies: Object {AWG: Object {name: "Aruban florin", symbol: "ƒ"}}
demonyms: Object {eng: Object {f: "Aruban", m: "Aruban"}, fra: Object {f: "Arubaise", m: "Arubais"}}
flag: ""
idd: Object {root: "+2", suffixes: ["97"]}
independent: false
landlocked: false
languages: Object {nld: "Dutch", pap: "Papiamento"}
latlng: [12.5, -69.96666666]
name: Object {common: "Aruba", native: Object {nld: Object {common: "Aruba", official: "Aruba"}, …}, official: "Aruba"}
region: "Americas"
status: "officially-assigned"
subregion: "Caribbean"
tld: [".aw"]
translations: Object {ces: Object {common: "Aruba", official: "Aruba"}, deu: Object {common: "Aruba", official: "Aruba"}, …}
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: show us what `countries` looks like. And also what does your `console.log` output is, and the desired result

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: Should be `const CountryInfo = ({data}) =>{`

Comment: There we go.. Wow... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work:

You're accessing `(data)` instead of `({data})` in `CountryInfo` component.

```js
const CountryInfo = ({data}) =>{
    return(
      <p>{data.name} {data.area} km<sup>2</sup></p>
  );
};

function App({countries}) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CountryInfo data={countries[0]} />
    </div>
  );
}

const root = document.getElementById('root')

const countries = [{
area: 180,
name: 'Aruba'
}]
ReactDOM.render(<App 
  countries={countries}
/>, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"><div>
```

Good Luck...